# Why is $B_{t}-tB_{1}$ independent of $B_{1}$

Tags: probability, probability-theory, normal-distribution, brownian-motion, independence

Let $(B_{t})_{t \in [0,1]}$ be a brownian motion. Show that $B_{t}-tB_{1}$ is independent of $B_{1}$

My idea: I need to find a linear transformation $A$ that renders $A \begin{pmatrix} B_{1}-B_{t} \\
B_{t}
\end{pmatrix}= \begin{pmatrix} B_{t}-tB_{1} \\
B_{1}
\end{pmatrix}$

I feel like this is impossible since $A$ is a linear transformation and can thus not contain $B_{t}$ or $B_{1}$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since the linear combinations of $V:=(B_t-tB_1,B_1)$ are Gaussian, $V$ is a Gaussian vector. It thus suffices to look at the covariance between the two components of $V$. 
Since $t\leqslant 1$, $\operatorname{Cov}\left(B_t,B_1\right)=t$ and $\operatorname{Cov}\left(-tB_1,B_1\right)=-t\operatorname{Cov}\left( B_1,B_1\right)=-t$.

Comment: Is there any way to use a linear transformation?

Comment: Sure: $A=\begin{pmatrix} -t & (1+t) \\ 1 & 1 \end{pmatrix}$

Comment: That should be $A=\left(\matrix{-t&1-t\cr 1&1\cr}\right)$.